# file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No error

Tags: php, file

I am new to php so still figuring things out. And I have two scripts one is getting datas from other but when I try to get it using `file_get_contents()` it returns `NULL` and I see the following in my error.log:

> [php7:warn] [pid 5524:tid 852] [client ::1:8677] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(usr.php?getinfobymd5=5f85783ad40df90c6485a3a176c41612):
>
> failed to open stream: No error in A:\Apache\www\index.php on line 6

How can I fix that and what '**No error**' error means??
Also I tried to change permissions allowing everybody to execute, write the file; And setting `allow_url_fopen` to On.

Comment: Start by showing us the actual code. Without it debuggin it is very difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the filename in quotes:

```
    file_get_contents('usr.php');
```

Comment: Remove the ?getinfobymd5=5f85783ad40df90c6485a3a176c41612 as you can not append a query parameter to a filename.

Comment: Try
file_get_contents('htt p://localhost/usr.php?getinfobymd5=5f85783ad40df90c6485a3a176c41612'); if you really want the query string.